# colocar variável em seletor jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, seletores

Pesquisei outras perguntas semelhantes, mas a respostas delas não me ajudaram até porque, o seletor que estou usando é diferente.

quero pegar um `tr` em um `tbody` de uma `table`, usando o seletor `nth-child(n)` mas no `n` eu quero colocar uma variável e fazer mais ou menos assim:

`$("tbody").find("tr:nth-child(' + posicao + ')").addClass("classe");`

desta maneira não esta funcionando, e nem de outras que tentei e vi nas resposta por aqui.

Comment: Tenta usar a função do jQuery específica pra isso, o `.eq(n);` - Ficaria assim `$("tbody").find("tr").eq(suaVariavel).addClass("foo");`

Comment: @dsantoro e a resposta? :)

Comment: Foi só uma sugestão não valia como resposta rs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estás a fazer mal a concatenação, deves usar "" ou '', mas aí estavas a usar os dois, ou seja as pelicas (' ') eram consideradas parte do seletor:

```js
posicao = 2;
$("tbody").find('tr:nth-child(' + posicao + ')').addClass("classe");
```

```css
.classe {
 background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```